# Transceive failed at reading on Ultralight C after successful authentication

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I write & read on Ultralight C NFC chips under Android 4.4.4.

### What works

- **Reading** of unlocked chip
- **Writing** on unlocked chip

### What doesn't work

- **Authentication** on locked chip
- **Reading *(transceive 0x30)* on locked chip**

### Code

```
    MifareUltralight mifare = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    try {
        mifare.connect();

        authenticate(tag, mifare);
        Log.d(TAG, "authenticate successful");
        
        int flag = 0;
        String message = "";
        int nbByte = 0;
        for(int page = 4; page < 39; page++) {
            byte[] cmd = {0x30, (byte) page};
            byte[] msg = mifare.transceive(cmd);

            // Misc...
        }
            

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException while reading MifareUltralight message...", e);
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (mifare != null) {
            try {
                mifare.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error closing tag...", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem : if the tag is locked, authentication goes well **then this script throws a `java.io.IOException: transceive failed` exception** from

- android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponsesOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52)
- android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)
- abdriud.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight.transceive(MaifareUltralight.java:215)

The *authenticate successful* is logged.

Comment: What's the implementation of the authenticate() method? Do you use reader mode or the regular tag dispatch system?

Comment: The authenticate() method transceives on 0xAF

Comment: Actually, authenticate also fails at transceive, I simply didn't catch the error. So basically, no transceive works once the chip is locked.

Comment: Then again, what's the implementation of the authenticate() method?